# Hacer uso de USING en c# y sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buen día,

Me gusta guiarme por las buenas practicas y estaba viendo que lo mejor en C# es utilizar las instrucciones USING para asegurar que las conexiones a la base de datos sean eficientes y a su vez el código y rendimiento del sistema tambien.

He venido mejorando mis querys que antes no estaban parametrizados y tambien quiero cambiar mi forma de conectarme y desconectarme a mi base de datos, es por ello, que estaba leyendo y quisiera saber si está es la forma correcta de hacer uso de los USING.

INSERT:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1; User Id=sa; Password=adminroot-2020; Initial Catalog=SEF; Pooling=False;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BienesDeUsoRubros([rubro]) VALUES(@rubro)", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rubro", lookUpEdit1.Text);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Mi consulta es: al usar mi cadena de conexión en un USING, no debo cerrar la base de datos? Otra duda, debo habilitar (true) el pooling de mi conexión? Que diferencia existe entre un Pooling desactivado y otro activado?

Saludos.

Comment: La respuesta a las dos preguntas la tienes en la documentación oficial de [SQLConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). Básicamente, debes de usar bloques Using siempre. El pool normalmente será true, ya que la gestión del mismo, es mucho más rápida. Cada vez que abres una nueva conexión, conlleva un coste. Sin embargo, si le dejas que las "reutilice", entonces el coste es mucho menor. Por tanto, los tiempos de ejecución y consumo de recursos mejoran.

Comment: Gracias Javi, tu el otro día me fuiste corrigiendo con algunas dudas que tenia, hoy ves mi código más limpio? ¿Hay algo más que pueda mejorar? Intento hacer todos los cambios de inmediato en la aplicación que dejó un antiguo programador con muchos huecos y malas practicas.

Comment: Otra consulta, la cadena de conexión la almaceno en una clase o en el archivo de configuración de mi proyecto? Cual es la mejor forma? Perdón por tantas preguntas, pero intento pulirme en el mundo de la programación y me gusta siempre ir bajo las buenas practicas. A veces leer la documentación no es suficiente para cortar con esas dudas que solo se pueden expresar a través de esta clase de foros.

Comment: Otra duda que tengo, es que uso DevExpress para desarrollar y veo que al usar Pooling=True, permanecen abiertas algunas conexiones al SQL Server, esto es correcto? Como se cuando una conexión debería estar cerrada y cuando permanecer abierta?

Comment: El código, es mucho mejor. La cadena de conexión, en principio es mejor en un archivo de configuración, pero no esta mal tampoco en una clase. En cuanto a DevExpress, no lo he utilizado nunca. Pero que queden conexiones abiertas no es malo, siempre que el gestor de conexiones, las pueda reutilizar. De ahí que se permita ese parámetro, porque abrir y cerrar una conexión lleva consumo de recursos, pero reutilizar una conexión no cerrada es casi gratis.

Comment: Gracias por tu paciencia en explicar cada pregunta. Te comentaba, porque en todos mis metodos abro y cierro la conexión, y cuando pooling es igual a False, normalmente veo en el sql profiler como cada consulta se cierra, además, de que no hay ninguna conexión hacia mis bases de datos, pero cuando Poolin es True, veo como en el sql profiler, algunas consultas no tienen cierre (por más que en mi metodo llamo a close() o uso using, se mantienen abiertas las conexiones y mi base va sumando en vez de una conexión varias... llegando hasta 4 o 5 conexiones a la misma base. Esto es normal?

Comment: Eso es normal. Se supone que el gestor de conexiones las elimina cuando le viene "en gana" porque liberar una conexión consume recursos. Pero tienes un artículo muy bien explicado que te dice algo así como que las libera pasados unos minutos cuando detecta inactividad.[Agrupación conexiones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling). Realmente la gestión del pool es complicada. Y meter mano en ella más. Pero es una opinión.

Comment: Si, leí ese articulo, pero de "enfermito" estaba ejecutando un query que me devuelve cuantas conexiones existen a la BD y veo que por más que se use el Pooling=True, el acumula conexiones, cuando la teoría dice "que reutiliza" la conexión, es decir, que si conecto dos veces contra esa misma base y la conexión está abierta, me utiliza esa unica conexión, cosa que no veo que haga. El comando en cuestión es el que figura acá: https://blog.guillen.io/2016/11/07/sql-server-listar-conexiones-activas/

Comment: Mas allá de leer sysprocessess, a lo mejor esto te ayuda un poco mas [Gestión de conexiones](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5630/understanding-sql-server-connection-pooling-in-adonet/). Si no ves correcta la idea, plantea una pregunta específica detallada en un nuevo hilo, ya que la página, ya nos sugiere utilizar el chat, por extenso en comentarios.

Comment: Hice exactamente el ejemplo que figura en esa página y mi SQL no agrupó dichas conexiones, lo mismo pasa con mi aplicativo en desarrollo, en vez de reutilizar las conexiones, crea una nueva conexión. Habrá algún otro motivo de fondo por lo que puede estar pasando esto? Hay algun manera de poder contactarnos de una manera más fluida para abordar el tema?

Comment: Tendrá que ver con DevExpress? Eso se escapa completamente a mis conocimientos. Es posible que tenga una gestión o implementación de conexiones propia. Quizá deberías de utilizar un foro de la herramienta o algo así. O plantear una pregunta mas específica, con todo el escenario haber si alguien puede ayudarte.

Comment: Lo he hecho en un proyecto nuevo, y sigue pasando de que la agrupación no funciona. Haré un hilo nuevo para evaluar este problema.